# Link to my story content type D7?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I have added many content to content type story. How will I link to the page that shows all the nodes with their teaser? What will the link be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your contents are promoted to front page, they will be shown on front page.

If you want to see your content in a seperate page or block you should create a *View* from your contents, with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module

Answer (score 1):

Drupal does not quite work like that; lists are not automatically created. You can use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create the list.

Views can output the data as a table, fields etc. Set the filter by type on the content drop down to 'story'. By creating a view type page you can also set the custom URL.